# Is HTTP session state preserved during application upgrade using Oracle's Weblogic hot deploy feature?

Tags: weblogic, session

When performing hot deploy of a new version of a Java web app in Weblogic, does the application server preserve and transfer the HTTP session state from the old version to the newly deployed one?

In other words, is there going to be any inconvenience (session lost) for a end-user who is transferred from old version to the new one?

Answer (score 0):

The feature you're looking for is called Side-by-side deployment.

[Here's a YouTube video which goes through all the steps to do this in the admin console](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ufRK29cLW9U), but a high level overview is as follows:

1. Go to the app in the deployments page in the console
2. Select (tick) the app and click update
3. Change the source path to the new version
4. Select the option to preserve current sessions

The current sessions and old version of the app should be preserved until all the sessions end or timeout and all new requests will go to the new version.